# No puedo ordenar de mayor a menor los datos de mi tabla

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo 3 columnas:

| columna1 | Columna2 | Columna3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 111111 | 1 |
| 444444 | 444444 | 4 |
| 333333 | 333333 | 3 |
| 222222 | 222222 | 2 |
| 555555 | 555555 | 5 |
| 666666 | 666666 | 6 |

Si hago click sobre `Columna1` , `Columna2` o `Columna3` la tabla se ordena de **menor a mayor**:

| Columna1 | Columna2 | Columna3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 111111 | 1 |
| 222222 | 222222 | 2 |
| 333333 | 333333 | 3 |
| 444444 | 444444 | 4 |
| 555555 | 555555 | 5 |
| 666666 | 666666 | 6 |

Pero si vuelvo a hacer click no se me ordena de mayor a menor, qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('th').each(function (columna) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            console.log("clickeado columna");
            let registros = $('table').find('tbody > tr').get();

            registros.sort(function (a, b) {
                console.log("sort");
                let valor1 = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);
                let valor2 = parseInt($(b).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);

                return valor1 < valor2 ? -1 : valor1 > valor2 ? 1 : 0
            });

            $.each(registros, function (indice, elemento) {
                $('tbody').append(elemento);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Utilice dos `console.log` para saber si, llegaba a la funcion y si entraba en `sort()`.

La primera vez que hago click sobre la columna, aparece:

```
"clickeado columna"
(672) sort
```

Y de la segunda vez en adelante:

```
"clickeado columna"
    (121) sort
```

Actualmente hay 122 registros en la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('th').each(function (columna) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            let registros = $('table').find('tbody > tr').get();

            registros.sort(function (a, b) {
                let valor1 = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);
                let valor2 = parseInt($(b).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);

                return valor1 < valor2 ? -1 : valor1 > valor2 ? 1 : 0
            });

            $.each(registros, function (indice, elemento) {
                $('tbody').append(elemento);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>11111</td>
        <td>11111</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>33333</td>
        <td>33333</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>22222</td>
        <td>22222</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>44444</td>
        <td>44444</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>66666</td>
        <td>66666</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>55555</td>
        <td>55555</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: y estas seguro que el evento click se esta ejecutando la segunda vuelta; estoy casi seguro que eso es lo que esta fallando...

Comment: Si, use un Console.log cada vez que se haga click sobre la columna y aparece el mensaje.

Comment: tambien entra en el metodo sort?

Comment: la primera vez que hago click, el console.log sale: `(672) sort`, y a partir de la Segunda vez se muestra `(121) sort `

Comment: no pues esta dificil asi ... si pudieras subir un ejemplo mas completo con el sniped podria ayudarte...

Comment: Lo primero que intenté fue poner un snippet, pero el Javascript tiraba error

Comment: que error tiraba a lo mejor no colocaste todo lo que se necesita...?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ahi agregue un snippet con el error..

Comment: Estás tratando de comparar valores de cadena (`valor1` y `valor2` son cadenas). Conviértelos a números (con `parseInt`) y funcionará. Saludos

Comment: y el error creo que es por que no incluyes el jquery y tampoco le pusisiste un html completo ...

Comment: El snippet no leerá tu código js porque no estás importando el cdn de jquery (estás usando uno local).

Comment: @MauricioContreras si esta convirtiendo a entero...

Comment: Saqué los `console.log` del snippet porque no permitia ver con claridad la tabla

Comment: Acaba de editarla, en el post original no lo hacía. Si la pregunta la van cambiando a diestra y siniestra los comentarios van quedando desactualizados. Puedes ver el post original y no había conversión alguna @ArcanisGK507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues el método `sort` siempre ordena "ascending", si quieres que cambie la dirección de ordenamiento tienes que agregar más código, te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo

```js
let sortDirection = 1;

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('th').each(function (columna) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            console.log("clickeado columna");
            let registros = $('table').find('tbody > tr').get();

            registros.sort(function (a, b) {
                console.log("sort");
                let valor1 = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);
                let valor2 = parseInt($(b).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 16);

                return valor1 < valor2 ? -1 : valor1 > valor2 ? 1 : 0
            });
            
            if (sortDirection === 1) registros.reverse();            
            sortDirection *= -1; // cambia la direccion cada vez que ordenas

            $.each(registros, function (indice, elemento) {
                $('tbody').append(elemento);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>11111</td>
        <td>11111</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>33333</td>
        <td>33333</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>22222</td>
        <td>22222</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>44444</td>
        <td>44444</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>66666</td>
        <td>66666</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>55555</td>
        <td>55555</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Héroe sin capa :D Mil gracias!